# How to register models within some other model (which is connected via foreign key) in django-admin?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

i have two models

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.full_name
class Article(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
```

now in the admin site i want to register the reporter's model and then when it is clicked the Article model objects can be added from within that reporter's model .. is it possible ?? if yes how to accomplish this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [inline model admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). In your `admin.py`, add the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article, Reporter

class ArticleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Article

class ReporterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ArticleInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Reporter, ReporterAdmin)
```